# How do you force evaluation of a value in R within a for loop?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

For *complicated reasons* I'm trying to spy on often-used I/O methods in R.

I've got working code but there's something going on I don't understand about R's evaluation which leads to a lengthy comment.

```
.spy.on.methods <- function() {                                                            
  attached.packages <- .packages()                                                         

  pkg.watch <- list(                                                                       
    "data.table" = "fread",                                                                
    "maptools" = "readShapePoly",                                                          
    "utils" = "read.csv"                                                                   
  )                                                                                        

  for (pkg in names(pkg.watch)) {                                                          
    methods <- pkg.watch[[pkg]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    if (pkg %in% attached.packages) {
      # replace now
      .replace.methods.with.spy(methods)
    } else {
      # replace them right after they're loaded
      setHook(
        packageEvent(pkg, "attach"),
        # parameters included for reader comprehension - we don't need or use them
        function(pkg.name, pkg.path) {
          # WARNING: you cannot use `methods` here. The reason is the value is             
          # mutated within this loop and R's lazy evaluation means that ALL                
          # hook functions will end up having a `methods` value from the final             
          # iteration of the loop                                                          
          .replace.methods.with.spy(pkg.watch[[pkg.name]])                                 
        },                                                                                 
        action = "append"                                                                  
      )                                                                                    
    }                                                                                      
  }                                                                                        
}
```

It seems to me that I should be able to replace

```
.replace.methods.with.spy(pkg.watch[[pkg.name]])
```

with

```
.replace.methods.with.spy(methods)
```

but it doesn't work. Diagnostic `print` statements indicate that in all cases `methods` has the value associated with `pkg.watch[["utils"]]`.

I feel as if some combination of `force`, `eval`, and `substitute` are the solution here but I have not yet found it. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Sort of a weird solution, but I'm pretty sure changing the `for` loop to `lapply` will solve your problem, since every iteration will have a separate environment. `force` is not the solution here; it's just syntactic sugar (`force(methods)` is the same as having a line that's just `methods` or `identity(methods)`) useful for showing you're forcing evaluation of an argument to a function (arguments are evaluated lazily).

Comment: Otherwise you could pass `methods` through to a function to create the function you want, e.g. `(function(methods) function(pkg.name, pkg.path) {...} )(methods = methods)` so the correct version is first on the search path, but I'm not sure that's clearer.